# On $k$-space density of states and semiclassical transport

Tags: solid-state-physics, density-of-states

I am reading Chapter 12 of Ashcroft and Mermin and I have a great many questions, but one sticks out in particular.

As background, we note that it can be shown quite generally (by applying Born-von Karman boundary conditions to a convenient volume $V$) that the "volume per $k$-state" in $k$-space is (in 3D) $\mathbf{\Delta k} = V/8\pi^3$. Thus, taking the very large $V$ limit and dividing by $V$ we find that the density of $k$-states (per unit real space volume) is $1/8\pi^3$. Now if I were to multiply this by the real and $k$-space volume measures $d\mathbf{k}d\mathbf{r}$ and then integrate over an entire primitive cell (leaving only the $d\mathbf{r}$ measure behind) then I ought to get the total number of $k$-states available (in a given band) *at $\mathbf{r}$ in the crystal in a volume $d\mathbf{r}$*. This last point (italicized) is what confuses me. When the original derivation for the allowable k-states proceeded (the standard Bloch theorem proof), we showed that some $\mathbf{k}$ (in a given band) indexed a unique electronic state (neglecting spin) throughout the whole crystal, but with the above I seem to have found that all of these $k$-states exist at each $\mathbf{r}$ in the crystal.

I note further the following: the derivation using the BvK boundary conditions proceeded in some finite volume $V$, before letting $V$ go to infinity while dividing by $V$. We then further assert/assume that all quantities (including $k$-space density) *per unit volume* are the same in the infinite $V$ and any finite $V$ cases. Thus it follows that we can recover the $k$-space density by multiplying the $k$-space density per unit volume (found in the infinite $V$ limit) by whatever the actual crystal $V$ is (actually finite). But here $d\mathbf{r}$ is not the entire crystal volume! It seems as though we are misusing the derivation done earlier in A&M (Ch. 8).

I suppose I am ultimately confused about the nature of density of states., but perhaps someone can explain the above since I am ultimately trying to understand the attached from page 221 of A&M. Equation 12.7 includes the Fermi function, but in a filled band at $T=0$ this evaluates to 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are computing sums over $k$, we have to include the volume per $k$-state this as part of our integration measure, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{\vec{k}}\to\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3k\,.
$$
This integral on its own (i.e., when the integrand is equal to 1) yields the total number of states, and therefore
$$
\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}d^3k
$$
is equal to the number of states in the volume $d^3k$, and hence
$$
\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}
$$
is equal to the number of states in the volume $d^3k$ per unit real-space volume. Thus
$$
\frac{d^3rd^3k}{(2\pi)^3}
$$
is equal to the total number of states in phase-space volume $d^3rd^3k$, or, roughly speaking, the total number of states "at" the phase-space point $(\vec{r},\vec{k})$.  (Multiplying by 2 for the two spin states then agrees with that paragraph from A&M.)

---

Now, if we integrate over just a single primitive unit cell in the reciprocal lattice, we should get
$$
\int_k \frac{d^3rd^3k}{(2\pi)^3} = \frac{d^3r}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{(2\pi)^3}{a^3}=\frac{d^3r}{a^3}\,,
$$
since$-$assuming a cubic lattice of lattice constant $a$ for convenience$-$${(2\pi)^3}/{a^3}$ is the volume of the primitive unit cell in $k$-space.  Since a single band "lives" in this region, what we should be left with is the total number of states in a single band *that are* "at" the point $\vec{r}$.  Note that this quantity *is not* the total number of states in a single band but rather a fraction of them, namely, the fraction $\frac{d^3r}{a^3}$ of them.

Now, when talking about *states*, this last paragraph doesn't make a lot of sense, because states don't live in $r$-space, they live in $k$-space, so we can't *really* talk about states that are "at" $\vec{r}$. However, assuming we have a filled band, we can interpret $\frac{d^3rd^3k}{(2\pi)^3}$ as the total number of *electrons* in the phase-space volume $d^3rd^3k$ (since all of these states are filled by electrons!), and hence, loosely speaking, $\frac{d^3r}{a^3}$ is on average the number of electrons occupying a particular band and "near" (i.e., within $d^3r$ around) the point $\vec{r}$ in real-space.

---

Finally, interpreting the paragraph from A&M, we note again that
$$
\frac{d^3rd^3k}{(2\pi)^3}
$$
as the total number of states in the phase-space volume $d^3rd^3k$, and hence if a band is filled,
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}
$$
is the phase-space density of electrons.  On the other hand, if the band is *not* filled, then, since some of those states are not filled, the electron number-density is therefore smaller than this value.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I follow. In particular, I'm not sure I agree when you say that the given expression is "is equal to the number of states in the volume $d^3k$ per unit real-space volume." It seems to me that, based on how you (and A&M) derived this, it is necessary to specify that it is the number of states per unit volume, but that it only gives a number of states when it's multiplied by the entire volume of the given crystal. This seems to be a pertinent distinction since, when we...

Comment: later integrate over an entire primitive cell at a given position in real space, the tacit suggestion is that each k value "exists" at each position in real space (or am I misunderstanding?).

Comment: Or, rather, I should say that your answer seems to suggest EVERY k value exists at each position in real space.

Comment: @1729_SR It's difficult for me to see where you're coming from. $\sum_{\vec{k}}(1)$ *must be* the total number of states, almost by definition.  Everything follows from there, as far as I can tell: dividing by $V$ turns it into a real-space density (i.e., quantity per unit real-space volume), and so multiplying by $d^3r$ turns it into a number of states "in" $d^3r$.  However, as my second-to-last paragraph says, it's neither useful nor correct to talk about the states as being "at" a point in real-space: the states live in $k$-space, after all. Instead, it's only once we are able to...

Comment: ...interpret the quantity as a *number-density* of electrons (i.e., we're only looking at the states that are occupied by electrons) that we can start talking about the number of electrons "near" $\vec{r}$, say.  Even then, I'm not sure that integrating over the 1st Brillouin zone and then calling that a density of electrons in real space is  all that useful (even if interpreted as an average).  The *phase-space* one maybe makes some sense, though, because then, as A&M goes on to do, one can use a Liouville's theorem argument.

Comment: On thinking about this more, I think my biggest source of confusion is with the identification of states at a given point in real space. Your equation in the middle section makes it clear that -- if we allow this admittedly nebulous identification -- the number of states in a volume given by the integration measure is small, since $\frac{d^3r}{a^3}\ << \frac{V}{a^3}\  = N$, where $V$ and $N$ are the total (real space) crystal volume and total number of primitive cells in the crystal, respectively...

Comment: Thus I will accept your answer, though I am still unclear on why this identification makes sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps another way of thinking about this is as follows. Suppose that there are $M$ (orthogonal) plane-wave states. From these plane-wave states, we can construct a set of orthogonal states that are maximally localized in $r$-space (just like the plane-wave states are maximally localized in $k$-space). The number $M$ of states is the same, but now they "live" in $r$-space rather than $k$-space, they will be equally spaced, and so it makes sense to "attach" states to particular points in space. @1729_SR

Comment: I guess the problem is then that it doesn't make sense to say they're localized in k-space, which this phase space discussion also seems to require.

Comment: Perhaps *another* way to think about is that what follows this paragraph is a *semi-classical* approximation, in which electrons can occupy states that are localized in both $r$- and $k$-space. The original calculation gives us the correct number of states (that live in $k$-space), but then, allowing for linear combinations of these that are localized in both $r$- and $k$-space *and* uniformly distributed in $k$- and $r$-space, we get a phase-space density of $1/4\pi^2$. This also allows us to interpret the integral over the first BZ.

Comment: Hi march, just returning here (still confused but I think closer to understanding after a reread of AM and your answer!). You write "Note that this quantity is not the total number of states in a single band but rather a fraction of them, namely, the fraction \frac{d^3r}{a^3} of them." I had thought this made sense, except that an integrating over $\mathbf{r}$-space would lead to multiplication by $V$, the volume of the macroscopic crystal, whereas $a^3$ (or $v$ more generally in a non- simple cubic crystal) would be the primitive unit cell volume. But then integration over $\mathbf{r}$ would

Comment: ...leads us to $V/v = N$ ($N$ being the number of primitive cells in the real finite crystal) states per band. Is this what you had in mind?